# How Do I Reset the Audio for iOS Simulator?

Tags: xcode, audio, ios-simulator, macos-sierra

I have an audio software on my mac called Soundflower which I use to reroute audio between different music production software.  Since switching my macbook's audio output from "Headphones" to "Soundflower (2ch)", even after setting it back to "Headphones", my iOS simulator is sending all it's audio through Soundflower.

How do I reset iOS Simulator's audio to sync up with my OS's current settings of "Headphone" output?